# How do I tell FindMinimum to only work with positive, real numbers?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I have a function that I'm trying to minimize.  It currently works reasonably well with this:

```
FindMinimum[{chiSquared[ber, btm, dsr, dcd], 
  0 < ber && 0 < btm && 0 < dsr && 0 < dcd}, {{ber, 1.}, {btm, 
   10^10}, {dsr, 1.}, {dcd, 1000}}]
```

But the conditions seem like extra work.  Is there an easier way to tell these kinds of functions that they should only consider positive, real numbers when working on a solution?

Comment: I do it like this: `vars = {ber, btm, dsr, dcd};
init = {1., 10^10, 1., 1000};
FindMinimum[{chiSquared[ber, btm, dsr, dcd], Thread[0 < vars]}, 
 Thread[{vars, init}]]` -- maybe it's better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
FindMinimum[{chiSquared[ber, btm, dsr, dcd], Element[{ber, btm, dsr, dcd}, PositiveReals]}, {{ber, 1.}, {btm, 10^10}, {dsr, 1.}, {dcd, 1000}}];
```