# Why is FindMinimum trying negative numbers when I constraint the values to be positive reals?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

This is a follow up to this question: [How do I tell FindMinimum to only work with positive, real numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220099/how-do-i-tell-findminimum-to-only-work-with-positive-real-numbers)
Using a constraint for positive, real numbers, I have the following statement:

```
FindMinimum[{chiSquared[ber, btm, dsr, dcd], ber > 0 && btm > 0 && dsr > 0 && dcd > 0}, {{ber, 1.}, {btm, 10^10}, {dsr, 1.}, {dcd, 1000.}}]
```

Without going into the functions that are being called, I get this output:

> FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value -3.67837*10^23-6.26338*10^14 I
>   is not a real number at {ber,btm,dsr,dcd} =
>   {-0.000112335,8.94475*10^7,1.2307,799.69}.

Why is **ber** going negative in the **FindMinimum** algorithm when I specifically told it that negative numbers won't work?  I tried adding a constraint of `Element[{ber, btm, dsr, dcd}, PositiveReals]` and got the same message.

Comment: It is probably caused by the algorithm `FindMinimum` used to solve the problem. You can read more details about what `FindMinimum` actually does [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#73716527) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html)